# How can I get icon from exe file and save to drive via Batch code

Tags: batch-file

May I need your help now, I have been searching all over in google but exactly I didn't get really answer so I am balance to put my question here.
How to get an icon for `.exe` file and save to hard drive using Batch code?
Thanks

Comment: There is no built-in command that can do such things; you'll need some third-party tools

Comment: Or a powershell script: [one](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/592770-extract-icon-from-exe-powershell), [two](http://scriptolog.blogspot.com/2007/12/extracting-icons-with-powershell.html), [three](http://powershellscripter.com/2014/10/07/get-the-icon-of-a-exe-file/), [four](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2011/09/26/extracting-icons.aspx), [five](http://www.hican.net/2014/05/powershell-extract-icon-files-from-executables/)

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on wOxxOm suggested above, you can do this with a PowerShell command within a batch script like this:

```js
@echo off
setlocal

set "exe_in=%~1"
set "ico_out=%~2"

set "psCommand="[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Drawing');^
[Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon(\"%exe_in%\").ToBitmap().Save(\"%ico_out%\")""

powershell -noprofile -noninteractive %psCommand%
```

Example usage:

```js
script.bat c:\portaputty\putty.exe putty.ico
```

... will save putty.ico to the current working directory.

---

Or if you'd like to have the script save to `basename.ico` without your having to specify argument 2, you can embellish a bit like this:

```js
@echo off
setlocal

set "exe_in=%~1"
set "out_dir=."

if not "%~2"=="" 2>NUL pushd "%~2" && ( call set "out_dir=%%CD%%" & popd )
set "ico_out=%out_dir%\%~n1.ico"

set "psCommand="[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Drawing');^
[Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon(\"%exe_in%\").ToBitmap().Save(\"%ico_out%\")""

powershell -noprofile -noninteractive %psCommand%
```

Example usage:

```js
script.bat c:\portaputty\putty.exe
```

... will save putty.ico to the current working directory.

```js
script.bat c:\portaputty\putty.exe "%temp%"
```

... will save %temp%\putty.ico.